# How much of Rick's backstory in S3E1 was real?

Tags: rick-and-morty

In S3E1, The Rickshank Rickdemption, Rick is shown lying to the aliens via a fake memory.  He tricks them into thinking the scribbles on the ground are the secret to interdimensional travel, but it's actually a computer virus. However, when questioned about how he could modify his memories, he says:

> *True*, but you can alter anything you want about a totally fabricated origin story.

Implying that what was shown was fake.

However, when he's talking to Morty at the end of the show, he says:

> I'm not driven by avenging my dead family Morty, that was fake. I-I-I'm driven by finding that McNugget sauce, I want that Mulan McNugget sauce Morty, that's my series arc Morty.

I'm not sure what to make of this. Was his family actually killed? Or was he just correcting the fake story he gave to Morty earlier?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to know - however, if they were killed then that means Beth (the original) would have been a second daughter, adopted, clone, etc...

Comment: How does saying it's fake at the end conflict with saying it was fake earlier?

Comment: Word of god says the entire thing was false, without a single ounce of truth to it.

Answer (score 4):

Rick and Beth's backstory has been kept vague by intention, so we can't give you an accurate answer. However, there are things worth noting:

- Rick could have invented the whole thing. However, it seems to fit the show's general theme if the fake story has at least a grain of truth in it. Rick's fake story seems to be the first teaser; maybe Season 3 will give us more information.
- Beth getting blown up, in my interpretation, is the first definitive cue to the viewer that the story is a lie. It makes us realize that the story we believed to be true is actually false.
- If Beth was a clone or other "reproduction", Rick would be less interested in her. Rick is barely interested in reality; he seems completely unwilling to accept something he knows is false and has a habit of shattering someone's sense of reality if Rick sees that it is a delusion. If Beth isn't his actual (non-clone) daughter, Rick would not stick around as much as he does.
- Beth has mentioned that Rick left her and her mom. As far as Rick is concerned, he would have never seen either of them die since he left them while they were alive.
- While Rick and "current" Beth are not from the same dimension, you could argue that both of them have a different experience of past events. However, when Rick jumped from the Cronenberg dimension to the post-Cronenberg dimension, he specifically tells Morty that he picked an incredibly similar dimension to jump to (and that there are only a handful of those left). Rick leaving Beth and her mom is the distant past. If the Cronenberg and post-Cronenberg dimensions are different in regards to Rick leaving, that would presumably create a *massive* difference in both Rick and Beth's (and by extension Morty's) life. So it's safe to assume that between these two dimensions, Rick and Beth's past is the same.

But the short answer is that **we simply do not know yet**. It's intentionally left vague by the show's creators.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is safe to assume that Beth and Beth's mother were not killed as shown, because, Beth is alive, and if only Beth's mother was killed I think Beth would have said something about that. Beth is always saying that Rick left "them", indicating he left both Beth and her mother.

Comment: That said, we don't know which timeline Rick C137 is actually from

Comment: @s3raph86:True, but both C137 Rick and "post-Cronenberg" Beth seem to agree on the same history of Rick leaving them, even when not in earshot of eachother. When making the jump from the Cronenberg dimension to the post-Cronenberg dimension; Rick specifically tells Morty he picked a dimension that is incredibly similar (he also says there's only a handful of others left to jump to). Rick leaving Beth is the distant past and, if different between these dimensions, would dramatically change the world in terms of Rick and Morty's lives.